# Drawable Animations on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently trying to make a game project containing custome made frame by frame animations, my problem is that I can't make 2 animations accure at the same time, I know how to make one animation after another but can't figure out how to make multiple animations simultaneously.

```
AnimationDrawable animation;
ivPlayer1.SetImageResource(ShootAnimation);
animation = (AnimationDrawable)ivPlayer1.Drawable;
animation.Start();
```

I've been also trying to delay animations using handlers but I don't know what they do:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Action changeAnimations = () =>
{
animatiosn and stuff...
}
h.PostDelayed(changeAnimations, animation.NumberOfFrames * 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle0" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle1" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle2" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle3" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle4" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle5" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle6" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle7" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/AkIdle8" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```